# Как определить уровень знания какого либо языка?

Tags: любой-язык

Многие разработчики на своих личных сайтах указывают уровень знания различных языков в процентах. И я задался вопросом, а как мне определить на сколько процентов  я знаю определённый язык.
В инете подходящей инфы найти не могу, в основном все пишут про иниора, мидла и сеньёра. Может тут кто подскажет как можно определить))

Comment: В процентах имеет значение только 0%. Потому что никто не знает какой уровень составит 100%.

Comment: Да даже с определением мидлов и сеньоров никто толком не может определиться, а посчитать проценты так вообще нереально

Comment: Тот, кто пишет уровень знаний какого-либо языка в процентах - очковтиратель. И работать будет наверняка так же.

Comment: Это кто, например, указывает свои знания языка программирования в процентах? Не знаю ни одного такого

Comment: Упоминание навыков в процентном соотношении не лучший способ показать свою профпригодность, скорее сбить с толку Вашего потенциального работодателя, который будет проверять, соответствуют ли Ваши знания тому уровню, который Вы указали.
Что касается распределения уровней, то приведу разъяснение из [ответа](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/136165/309834).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 3):

Это довольно интересный вопрос, которым наверное задаются большинство разработчиков. Нашел на просторах сети такую интересную картинку (все субъективно):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваш уровень знания того или иного языка программирования зависит только от ваших знаний. Всем известно что можно разграничить уровни так: Junior, Middle, Senior. Чаще всего для определения своего уровня, человек использует найденные в сети сроки работы на том или ином поприще. Но мне кажется это не очень правильно, так делать. Например, человек устроился работать каким-то абстрактным разработчиком и у него были какие-то абстрактные задачи. Человеку было сначала сложно, и понятно, ведь он только пришел на эту должность. Дальше человек наловчился и хорошо разбирается в том как делать свои задачи. Но чаще всего когда вы работаете вам дают однотипные задачи, и как-бы застываете на каком-то уровне выполняя их. Но вернемся к нашему абстрактному девелоперу: просидел он например два года выполняя одно и то же, и потом говорит - я уже не джуниор а миддл, ведь я работаю на этом должности целых два года. Но он сидел и делал одно и тоже два года и до миддла ему еще расти и расти. Возьмем другой пример - пришел человек, ничего не знающий, и начал работать. Но ему "повезло" больше чем первому герою и он попал в мясорубку: выучил оочень много всего и после двух лет он легко ориентируется во всех вопросах касающихся его должности, но тем не менее он уверен что он все еще джуниор. Суть басни такова - старайтесь развиваться всегда когда есть возможность, совершенствуйтесь постоянно, и не задирайте нос (без обид если что) когда вас поднимают над другими разработчиками. Всего не знает никто, с такой мыслью нужно тормозить свои порывы учить что-то новое - можно выгореть и тогда вас сложно будет вернуть в строй. Вот нашел несколько ссылок которые возможно помогут в решении дилеммы касательно вашего уровня:

1. [ссылка 1](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_we_measure_programming_skills)
2. [ссылка 2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25707/how-to-measure-his-own-skill-in-a-programming-language)
3. [ссылка 3](https://science.raphael.poss.name/programming-levels.html)
4. [ссылка 4](https://www.altexsoft.com/blog/business/software-engineer-qualification-levels-junior-middle-and-senior/)
5. [ссылка 5](https://medium.com/better-programming/the-differences-between-a-junior-mid-level-and-senior-developer-bb2cb2eb000d)

P.S. извините если много текста написано, хотелось чтобы было понятно не только мне :)